# Why is my list comprehension causing the code to return my entire text document rather than only matches of words from permutations of a word?

Tags: python, iteration, permutation, python-itertools

My code:

```
from itertools import permutations 

original = str(input('What word would you like to unscramble?: '))

inputFile = open('dic.txt', 'r')
compare = inputFile.read().split('\n')
inputFile.close()



for now in permutations(original):
    car = [print(now) for now in compare if now in compare] #supposed to compare iterations of input word to text file.
```

I am trying to unscramble a word by finding all permutations of a word and running each permutation through a text file of English words to see if it is a real word or not. My previous version stored all the permutations in a list (now I know that's a bad idea). This code here just prints my entire text file, and I'm not entirely sure why. I would like to know what I'm doing wrong with the list comprehension that prints the entire text file of words rather than only iterating through the permutations of the input word.

Comment: Why are you both looping over `compare` *and* testing against `compare`? by definition all your words will match.

Comment: You cannot use `now` both for the loop variable and the loop variable in the list comprehension here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make you code more python-idiomatic in multiple ways:

```
from itertools import permutations 

original = str(input('What word would you like to unscramble?: ')) 

with open('dic.txt') as input_file:
    compare = input_file.readlines()

for permutation in permutations(original):
    if permuation in compare:
        print(permutation)
```

Does this do what you are looking for?

Comment: It looks like it does, but when I run it and I input a word I know is in the list, it still returns nothing. Also, does using with and as make it different than doing inputFile = open('dic.txt')?

Comment: You need to `''.join(permutation)` before checking compare as it will be a list of letters rather than a word.

Comment: @SteveBarnes is right with his comment. You need to join the permutations first. Using `with` enables you to not care about closing the files (even in the event of an error etc) which is quite nice

Comment: @SteveBarnes I changed the code to include this and it still returns nothing.

Comment: How does your `dic.txt` look like?

Comment: @k-nut One word per line.

Comment: `readlines` keeps a `\n` at the end of each line that you need to get rid of. Try: `compare = [word.strip() for word in input_file.readlines()]`

Comment: It still returns nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64548/discussion-between-k-nut-and-timewilltell).